# How do I access ng-model values inside my directive template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive with a template that looks like

```
<!-- selectList.tpl.html -->
<div ng-if="selectList">
  <p>Id: {{$id}}</p>
  <p>Current list item {{currentItem}}</p>
  <select ng-model="currentItem"
    name="current-item"
    ng-options="item as item.value group by item.group for item in selectList">
    <option value="">All</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I'm trying to access the `currentItem` value from inside my directive link function to create a watch function ie,

```
app.directive('selectList', [
  "$rootScope",
  "$timeout",
  function (
    $rootScope,
    $timeout
  ) {
    "use strict";

    var getList = function() {
      // ...
    };

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'selectList.tpl.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.selectList = getList();
        scope.currentItem = "";

        console.log("scope id:", scope.$id);

        scope.$watch('currentItem', function(item) {
          $timeout(function() {
            console.log("currentItem is", item);
            angular.element("#console").append("<p>Updated item: " + item + "</p>");
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }
}
```

However, a child scope is created under the linkscope which stores changes to the values of the select box. How do I access the select box changes inside my directive link code?

I'm using Angular 1.1.5.

Here is a plunker of the problem (have updated code in the q to reflect the plunker): http://plnkr.co/edit/5eOaRE?p=preview

Comment: could you set up a plunkr if you've got a few minutes.

Comment: hard to tell what scopes you have at play without showing directive code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ng-if is creating another scope.  So when you update the value in the child scope it is not updating the parent scope.

See updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3sXPZmhkOJd5uhMJkICx?p=preview

If you need to keep the ng-if you will need to call a function defined in the parent scope from the child scope.

Comment: Ah, that was it! I got it working without the extra `scope` directive attribute too: http://plnkr.co/edit/uJBzuv?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a scope in your directive and set up two-way binding with an attribute.  For example:

```
<my-directive attr="myVal">

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            attr: '=',
        },
        template: '<select ng-model="attr"> ... </select>',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

You should theoretically be able to use ng-model directly, but I had trouble with it.  If the attribute name and the variable name declared in scope are the same, you can use the scope the way I wrote in the example.  Otherwise, you will have to be more specific.

Comment: Here's what I have in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5mzGVF?p=preview - doesn't work though.